# Pandas - How to combine duplicate items into one with several columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multiple-columns, data-preprocessing

I have the below DataFrame

[image: dataframe]

As you can see, ItemNo 1 is duplicated three times, and each column has a value corresponding to it.

I am looking for a method to check against all columns, and if they match then put Price, Sales, and Stock as one entry, not three.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove all the NaN instances and redefine the column names

```
df = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
df.columns = ['ItemNo','Category','SIZE','Model','Customer','Week Date','<New col name>']
```

For converging to one row, you can use `groupby` like this

```
df.groupby('ItemNo', as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for this! I am a lot closer, but with this method, I am still getting ItemNo 1, three times, and each instance has its own value.                                                                                              I am trying to change it so ItemNo1 has only one row, and three columns with the corresponding values

Comment: Hey, I updated it, you can you groupby to resolve it

Comment: That is great, thank you! Is there an additional option to groupby more fields? I believe I am deleting a lot of values, ideally I would need to check all of the columns before 'Price' and if all of these match do the groupby operation :) (The dates and itemno are often the same, different customer etc)

Comment: Yes you can `df.groupby(['ItemNo', 'Category' ,'Size',...], as_index=False).first()` for multiple columns and add more in same way :)

Comment: Life saver! Pandas is so neat, thank you dude!